# Display a div in the center of the page, when I click on any part of a section

Tags: html, css

I need help, I have this code:

html:

```
<section  id="about" class="grid_4">
 <header id="headerabout">The header</header>
  <img id="imgabout" src="../images/software.svg"/>
   <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    <div class="hidden">This should be displayed</div>
</section>
```

css:

```
*{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: white;
margin: auto;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
section {
height: auto;
z-index:15;
overflow: auto;
}

p {
padding: 2px;
}


#headerabout {
height: 24px;
width: 296px;
margin-top: 2px;
}

#about {
height: 380px;
background-color: green;
}

height: auto;
background-color: #b01f1c;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
text-align: center;
```

and I want to make it so that wherever you click on the section, it fades the screen to black, opacity 0.8 (I already know how to do that) and displays a div in the center of the screen with extra information, which can be closed and you can return to the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery:

```
$("section").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
});

$(".close-btn").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/XbNC8/

Comment: Grrh. You were too fast... Great solution :D